# May a player try to hunt again if his cards were sniped?

Tags: arctic-scavengers

Say an opponent decides to hunt with a scavenger. You play a sniper from your hand and snipe the scavanger. Since this hunt "didn't happen" may the opponent try to hunt again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [BGG FAQ about snipers and saboteurs](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1052134/complete-faq-about-sniperssaboteurs)

> Q. If a player has been sniped or sabotaged while resource gathering,
>   is he still required to use or discard the other cards he played for
>   hunting/hiring, digging, or drawing?
>
> A. No, only the card that was sniped/disarmed is discarded, and all
>   other cards involved in that action can be taken back into hand and
>   re-purposed to perform a different hunt/hire, dig or draw action, or
>   to do something else entirely.

Yes, they can re-use the item(s) and attempt the action again (this is specifically stated [in another thread](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/3634508#3634508) by the designer).